# Why is Java labelling this class as abstract

Tags: java, abstract

Please see code here. Java is labeling this class as abstract, and I can't instantiate it... Any ideas why??

```
public class Marker {
    Location l;
    int xcoord;
    int ycoord;
    int value;

    Marker(int x, int y, int val){
        xcoord=x;
        ycoord=y;
        value = val;
        l = new Location(x,y); 
    }
}
```

re: code to instantiate:

...I'm reading through a large file of data that's separated by tabs. After ever 16th tab there is a marker, usually of value 0. If it's not 0, I want to save the location and value as a Marker... The values for x, y, tabcounter, and currchar are being updated as I iterate through the file.

```
if (tabcounter == 16) { //now we are at a marker
    if (currchar != 48) { //if the marker isn't 0

        Marker m = new Marker(x,y,(int)(char)currchar);
        markers.add(m); //markers is a list of type Marker
    }
    tabcounter = 0;
    x=0;
    y=y+1;
}
```

Comment: What makes you say 'Java is labelling it as abstract'?

Comment: when i refactor the name to 'maker' with lowercase m, there's no problem...

Comment: when i try to instantiate - 

Marker x = new Marker(1,2,3); 

can't compile, error in netbeans says that the class 'Marker' is abstract

Comment: Do you have a name clash with an existing class then?

Comment: @Matt show your code where you try to instantiate the class

Comment: It's not abstract.  It just has no public constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Check your buildpath to see if there are any other classes named Marker. It could be in a jar file somewhere. If you are using eclipse, use the "link with Editor" option to find which Marker it is looking for by highlighting the class name.